# Why is the first bullet of my list larger than the rest?

Tags: lists, itemize

In the environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{description}}
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{\item[$-$]\small{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{description}\vspace{-5pt}}

\begin{document}
    \resumeItemListStart

       \resumeItem{A}
         
       \resumeItem{B}
        
       \resumeItem{C}
        
       \resumeItem{D} 

    \resumeItemListEnd
\end{document}
```

Why is the first bullet `-` of item A longer than the rest?

Screenshot attached below.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please, add a full example of the code you're using.

Comment: As egreg said, make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Thanks for the MWE. `\small` is a switch; it does not take parameters. Replace it with `\huge` or `\tiny` (also switches) to see  the effect.

Comment: @Cicada That did the trick, thank you!

Comment: You can self-answer and self-accept, to show people what worked for you.

Comment: Kind of off topic: `description` is for if the thing in `[]` is a word that needs describing.  If it's the same every time, then you have an `itemize` and enumitem would let you say `\begin{itemize}[label=$-$]`.  If the letters are supposed to be there (not just for your MWE), then you have an `enumerate` and enumitem would let you say `\begin{enumerate}[label=$-$ \alph*]`.  And it doesn't quite make sense to have `\resumeItem` take two arguments but use only one (although that could be just for your MWE as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `\small` from `\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{\item[$-$]\small{{#1}}}` did the trick!